# Can a Hat of Wizardry be reused by different people attuning?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement

Say I have a Hat of Wizardry. It allows me to try to cast a cantrip once per long rest. If I use this power and fail my Arcana check (or succeed - it doesn't matter for this), can a friend attune to it, try again, and give the magic item back to me?

I expect that RAI is for that item to be usable only once per day by anyone, but I think that in this case it can be used by several people each day. Am I right, or does something contradict this? I want to know the RAW in this case, but if we know about the designers' intent here, that's useful as well.

Comment: The answers to your other questions about multiple creatures attuning to a single item seem to cover the subject well enough already. What don't they cover that this one does?

Comment: On the surface, this would be a question with a clear answer, but due to your other questions, there might be another issue here - would you mind elaborating what you see as conflicting/confusing?

Comment: This can be independent from multiple creatures attuning to a single item. Alice uses the hat, party takes a short rest, Bob attunes to the item, Bob tries to use the hat.

Comment: @OganM In itself I would agree, I almost answered it myself. But a) I don't see how the answer would address anything that the other questions haven't, and b) the questions as a whole [are starting to fit a distressing pattern](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9767/40335).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, but note that the *Hat of Wizardry* is unusual in that respect

The text of the Hat of Wizardry gives it the following ability (XGtE, p. 137, bold and italics added):

> You can try to cast a cantrip that you don't know. The cantrip must be on the Wizard spell list, and you must make a DC 10 Intelligence (Arcana) check. If the check succeeds, you cast the spell. If the check fails, so does the spell, and the action used to cast the spell is wasted. In either case, ***you* can't use this property again until *you* finish a long rest**.

The prohibition against using the cantrip granting property of the hat is restricted to the particular person who used it (i.e. "you."). **If a different person were to attune to the hat (who would also need to be a wizard), they would be able to use this property immediately**, regardless of whether or not the hat's previous user had completed a long rest.

### Could this be used to get around most time-limited magic items?

No. Nooooooo. No, it couldn't.

**The *Hat of Wizardry* is very unusual** in that it relies on a long rest by the user to recharge its utility, and *says that specifically that user* cannot do so until then. Many magical items require time to be used again, but they often rely on specific times to occur (e.g. dawn) or the use of a finite or renewable resource (e.g. "charges") to use. **And more importantly, these other items often cease to work for *anyone* (not just the current user) until those requirements are met.**  For example, consider the item Cloak of the Bat (DMG, p. 159, bold added):

> While wearing the cloak in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your action to cast *polymorph* on yourself, transforming into a bat... **The cloak can't be used this way again until the next dawn.**

Now, if this cloak was used to cast polymorph at midnight, and then attuned to by a new user one hour later (assuming "dawn" happens at 6am), it couldn't be used to cast polymorph again because the "next dawn" hadn't occurred yet. And the cloak doesn't say that only the previous user had to wait: it said that "the cloak can't be used this way again until the next dawn," which would apply to anyone.

As another example, consider the Boots of Speed (DMG, p. 155, bold added):

> While you wear these boots... the boots double your walking speed... When the boots' property has been used for a total of 10 minutes, **the magic ceases to function** until you finish a long rest.

This is an item, like the *Hat of Wizardry*, that requires the user to take a long rest to recharge it. However, unlike the *Hat of Wizardry*, this item would not work for a new user either! It does not say that the boots stop working "for you" (the attuned creature): it says the "magic ceases to function," which would apply to new users as well: and it triggers when the "boots' property has been used for 10 minutes", not when the *current user* has used them for that amount of time. The DM would have to decide whether it was the previous user or the new one who had to take a long rest to recharge the boots, but regardless, they would not function for a newly attuned user until that long rest had occurred.

So **although the Hat of Wizardry could definitely be used to cast unknown cantrips in one day by multiple wizards** (once each), note that **many other magic items which require time to "recharge" will *not* be similarly reusable just because someone new attuned to them**. You'll need to consider it on an item by item basis.

Comment: Note (that I don't think belongs in the actual question): I have found at least one other item that would be usable by multiple attuners in one day. The *Rod of the Pact Keeper* (DMG, p. 197) allows an attuned Warlock to regain a warlock spell slot, and says "You can't use this property again until you finish a long rest." Items like this are very rare (I've only found a few), but I didn't want to imply that the *Hat of Wizardry* was unique in this respect.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes

> While you are wearing it, **you** gain the following benefits:

The “you” is the person currently attuned to the item. If you have 6 wizards in your party then, given enough short rests, each can attune to it once between long rests and try to cast a cantrip.